# How to use an application in docker with postgres database in heroku

Tags: docker, heroku, heroku-postgres

How to use an application in [docker](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime) without using [heroku.yml](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml) approach with postgres database?

Comment: Don't run your own database server in Docker. Instead, use a proper hosted database service like [Heroku's own Postgres service](https://www.heroku.com/postgres), an [official addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores), or something like [Amazon RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/) or [Azure Database for PostgreSQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/postgresql/).

Comment: @Chris thanks for response. I tried to use https://www.heroku.com/postgres service, but I failed(

Comment: "but I failed"—how, exactly? If that's your problem, [ask about _that_, not whatever you think the solution might be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Comment: @Chris sorry, I think I misspelled the question(

Comment: @Chris to each his own, I prefer managing my infrastructure than using hosted services - cbf dealing with support lines.

Comment: @masseyb, fine, but don't host your database on Heroku alongside your app container. Heroku is built for easy horizontal scaling. Do you really want a second copy of Postgres if you add a second web dyno? Probably not. Decouple your database from your application code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I could pass database settings as an environment variables with the help of heroku [Config Vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

You could find an example [here](https://github.com/vmaks/java-getting-started/blob/master/README.md).

[image: Heroku Config Vars]